# Cannot build react native on Mac Ventura 13.4

Tags: android, ios, react-native

Hello react native and mobile developers!

I am currently working on react native application and it works with android, also worked on Mac 11, but when I try to build on Mac OS 13.4 It failed with below errors.

In order to fix issues, I updated ruby version from some references (from 2.7 to 3.2.0 using rbenv)

```
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SynkBooks-bghxbttcyzckrieohotoymzblpqz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-Codegen.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FBReactNativeSpec-generated.o /Users/user/Desktop/Work/synkbooks_app_v1/ios/build/generated/ios/FBReactNativeSpec/FBReactNativeSpec-generated.mm normal x86_64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'React-Codegen' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure)
]
```

`npx react-native info`

```
System:
    OS: macOS 13.4
    CPU: (16) x64 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-11700 @ 2.50GHz
    Memory: 310.96 MB / 31.63 GB
    Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 18.16.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/bin/yarn
    npm: 9.5.1 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.16.0/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2023.05.22.00 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.12.1 - /Users/user/.rbenv/shims/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 22.4, iOS 16.4, macOS 13.3, tvOS 16.4, watchOS 9.4
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2022.2 AI-222.4459.24.2221.10121639
    Xcode: 14.3/14E222b - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.19 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0 
    react-native: 0.71.4 => 0.71.4 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by adding below code snippet to Podfile.

```
__apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
      if target.name == "React-Codegen"
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.4'
        end
      end
    end
```

and then go to /ios folder and run pod install again. :)